# What does 'get + adjective' mean?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Can you tell me what means **get + adjective**? I do not understand it. Can you tell me more about this grammatical structure?

I found this sentence in one book.

> As we **get older** we need less sleep.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, all 'get' means here is 'become'.

So 'As we get older' just means 'as we become older'.

We use this a lot in English, for instance: 'you will get taller', 'you might get richer', etc.